# Typing chemical formula using markdown

Tags: html, markdown

I'm writing some material using *Markdown* on *Mou*.
And the chemical formula need to be used frequently.
For example, I would typing

```
 H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>
```

Then, the sulfate acid can be represent as H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub> .
But I can't figure out how to represent the anion type formula in html.
The figure shows like this:

[image]

I try to typing

```
 SO<sub>4><sup>2-</sup></sub>
```

It shows like this: SO<sub>4<sup>2-</sup></sub>

Comment: That's because you but the `<sup></sup>` tags in the `<sub></sub>` tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `<sup>` for the charge:

```html
H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub> + 2NaOH &rarr; 2H<sub>2</sub>O + Na<sup>+</sup> + SO<sub>4</sub><sup>2-</sup>
```

gives:

H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub> + 2NaOH → 2H<sub>2</sub>O + Na<sup>+</sup> + SO<sub>4</sub><sup>2-</sup>

See this sample: https://jsfiddle.net/cp4n31qx/1/

Answer (score 3):

This would even work without the CSS, I just used it to make it look better, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w4Lgj6xt/) is a fiddle

HTML

```
<div>
  <h2>
  SO<sub>4</sub><sup>2-</sup>
  </h2>
</div>
```

CSS

```
sub {
  font-size:13px;
}

sup {
  font-size:13px;
  margin-left:-5px;
}
```